# Pug support in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, pug

I am trying to add Pug support in Intellij IDEA.

File->Settings->Editor->Code Style->File Types.

But there is no Jade or Pug under the Recognized File Types list.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that [Pug](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7094-pug-ex-jade-/) plugin is installed and enabled in **Settings | Plugins**. This plugin is not bundled with IDEA and has to be installed separately. see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.3/jade.html.

Note that it can't be installed in IDEA Community edition, you need Ultimate to use it.